# Loop is much faster as a for loop than a while loop, then when statement is changed, the while loop is faster. What happens?

Tags: c#, performance

Out of interest, I tested if there was any difference to a for loop and a while loop doing the same thing. What causes the while loop to take about 2-2.5 seconds longer on my computer (AMD Phenom II X6 1090T @ 3.20GHz) than the for loop? Aren't they doing the same thing? Do you get similar results?

Also, when I replace the `x = null;` statement from the loops with just an empty statement, the while loop will be significantly faster. What's going on here?

Sure, the number of iterations is pretty high, but isn't the difference still pretty significant?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    String x;
    const Int64 FIVE_BN = 5000000000;
    Int64 i = 0;

    DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
    for (; FIVE_BN > i; i++)
        x = null; //Replace with only ; in both loops and the for loop is faster
    Console.Out.WriteLine(FIVE_BN.ToString() + " times (for): " + (DateTime.Now - start));

    i = 0;

    start = DateTime.Now;
    while(FIVE_BN > i++)
        x = null; //Replace with only ; in both loops and the for loop is faster
    Console.Out.WriteLine(FIVE_BN.ToString() + " times (while): " + (DateTime.Now - start));

    Console.Read();
    return;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `DateTime` for benchmarks - use the `Stopwatch` class which is intended for such use.

Comment: Perhaps something has been optimized by your compiler.

Comment: Just a couple of pointers, try to use `Stopwatch` for performance timing purposes, and do multiple runs to filter out the overhead of a cold-run being JIT'd (ignore the first run basically).

Comment: Thanks for the Stopwatch tip.. it seems when I use Stopwatch, the for loop is faster in both cases. The difference is still more than 1 second for the empty statement though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While this is entirely a micro optimization that would never be the performance bottleneck. It interesting that the two are actually different, interestingly when you extract methods both the loops with VS2010 I get the following:

```
private static String forLoop(ref Int64 i)
{
    String x;

    for (; FIVE_BN > i; i++)
        x = null; //Replace with only ; in both loops and the for loop is faster
    return x;
}

private static void whileloop(ref String x, ref Int64 i)
{
    while (FIVE_BN > i++)
        x = null; //Replace with only ; in both loops and the for loop is faster
}
```

And that is quite interesting... it shows that the two functions are indeed different.

now when we replace the logic in the loop with `;` we get the following extracted methods instead:

```
private static Int64 forLoopShort(Int64 i)
{

    for (; FIVE_BN > i; i++)
        ; //Replace with only ; in both loops and the for loop is faster
    return i;
}

private static Int64 whileLoopShort(Int64 i)
{

    while (FIVE_BN > i++)
        ; //Replace with only ; in both loops and the for loop is faster
    return i;
}
```

Which indicates why the loops run basically the same with this configuration.

To work out how they're different when inline (and not extracted into methods) we need to see what the optimized CLR coded looks like (though the optimizer might actually remove any significant differences between the two functions).. That's something for a later edit.

Edit:

The CIL reveals the differences:

The For loop has `.maxstack  2` but the while loop has `.maxstack  4`, otherwise there's a little diference in the order of operations due to the fact that the increment for the `while` happens at the start of the loop but the `for` operation happens at the end of the loop (change the content of the loop to `Console.WriteLine(i)` and see that the While loop will print from 1 but the For loop will print from 0 (both do the same number of loop iterations though).

When the loop contents is just a `;` both loops are 2 lines shorter in CIL with the following lines removed (for both loops):

```
IL_0006:  ldnull
IL_0007:  stloc.0
```

However when we build in release the code is very different:

The difference between `x = null;` and `;` is nothing, for either of the loops, as the optimizer has noticed that the value never changes to being not-null.

The difference between the optimised for and while loops are as follows:

CIL `for` loop:

```
IL_0000:  ldc.i4.0
IL_0001:  conv.i8
IL_0002:  stloc.0
IL_0003:  br.s       IL_000a
IL_0005:  ldloc.0
IL_0006:  ldc.i4.1
IL_0007:  conv.i8
IL_0008:  add
IL_0009:  stloc.0
IL_000a:  ldc.i8     0x12a05f200
IL_0013:  ldloc.0
IL_0014:  bgt.s      IL_0005
IL_0016:  ret
```

And CIL `while` loop:

```
IL_0000:  ldc.i4.0
IL_0001:  conv.i8
IL_0002:  stloc.0
IL_0003:  ldc.i8     0x12a05f200
IL_000c:  ldloc.0
IL_000d:  dup
IL_000e:  ldc.i4.1
IL_000f:  conv.i8
IL_0010:  add
IL_0011:  stloc.0
IL_0012:  bgt.s      IL_0003
IL_0014:  ret
```

So we can see that an optimised while loop is faster than a for loop by 2 operations, however it uses more stack space.

The difference between these two seems entirely related to the difference in where the `i++` occurs.

Indeed this is confirmed by making a new method:

```
private static void forLoopVeryShort()
{
    string x;
    Int64 i = 0;

    for (; FIVE_BN > i++;)
        ; //Replace with only ; in both loops and the for loop is faster
}
```

The CIL code for this `for` method when built (in either release or debug) is identical to that of the `while` loop.

There in lies your difference. For loops perform exactly the same as while loops when they're doing the exact same behaviour. The difference you noted is entirely due to running the code in debug and not release, combined with the JIT not always being as efficient as the release code optimizer.

I have enjoyed this question, I learnt something out of it; I hope others do as well. +1

Comment: Wow! + for effort. Very interesting. Looking forward to any edit :)

Comment: And there you go, that's why the two loops **do** perform different.

Comment: Excellent... As mentioned in the other answers, it's a microoptimization that we probably shouldn't be bothered to look for, but thanks for actually answering the question:) I like to get to the bottom of things, it suddenly doesn't seem so mysterious.

Answer (score 8):

You'd probably want to break out cordbg (and carefully enable all JIT optimizations) to look at the generated native code to work out exactly why this was happening... but why bother? In *real* code, the difference won't be significant, because you'll be doing real work in the loop.

Micro-optimizing completely unrealistic code isn't a fruitful exercise, IMO. Even micro-optimizing real code is *usually* not fruitful, unless you've already verified that this is the bottleneck.

Comment: +1 If the difference fluctuates due to the code inside the loop as well, the difference might not even *exist* in the wild, let alone be anywhere near a performance problem.

Comment: You are probably right. I'll start worrying about this if the difference is still significant when doing real work.

Comment: +1 When I actually looked at the generated CIL instructions, it becomes easily clear why the two loops actually perform different

Answer (score 3):

For info - cannot repro:

with the assignment:

```
5000000000 times (for): 00:00:15.0488608
5000000000 times (while): 00:00:12.7107270
```

with just a `;`

```
5000000000 times (for): 00:00:15.0558611
5000000000 times (while): 00:00:12.7297281
```

(here, I am running in release mode, outside the debugger, etc)

It is *possible* that this is Framework specific (I'm using 4.0.30319.488, x64) or CPU-specific (I'm using an Intel i7 4x2.67GHz (plus HT)), but my first guess would be *how* the test is being run.

Comment: You are right it seems... I checked, and seem to get vastly different results according to how I run the test, and even the order of which kind of loop runs first. This difference seems to be caused by everything else but the theoretical code itself.

Comment: +1 making sure the code is run through the JIT once already combined with running in release mode with optimizations makes all the difference to the execution times